# $i$ to the power of $i$ to the power of $i$ infinitely?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations

How could you evaluate $i$ to the power of $i$ which is the to the power of $i$ with infinitely many $i$ exponents? My initial idea was to set it all equal to x which allowed me to write:

$$i^x=x$$

I tried a couple of different ways to solve this but struggled to get anywhere. When I put this equation in Wolfram alpha they use $W_n$ term that I am unfamiliar with. Could someone please explain to me what this means or if there is any alternative ways to solve this problem?

Comment: It is $i^{i \cdot i \cdot i \cdots }$ which does not converge. Do you mean a [power tower](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180936/complex-towers-iii) with $i$ instead? See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336702/infinite-powering-by-i).

Comment: Hi :) I don't believe, that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ with $a_{n+1}=a_n^i,\ a_0=i$ converges. It's periodic, since $i^4=1$.

Comment: It is not hard to see that the sequence is $i, e^{-{\pi \over 2}}, -i, e^{{\pi \over 2}},...$

Comment: Sorry I meant each i is to the power of the last i not to the power of the whole thing, I'm not to sure how to format that correctly it gives me an error message when I try to type it like that.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to write it as a power tower but couldn't format it.

Comment: Generally, equations like $a^x=x$ involve something like "Lambert's W function" and won't have nice solutions that are easily written down. Maybe there is some complex analysis that at least proves one or more solutions exist though.

Answer (score 1):

From the euler formula we know that
$$i=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$$
Which means that
$$i^i= \left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}\right)^i=e^{\frac{i^2\pi}{2}}$$
and for n powers of $i$
$$(((i^i)^i)^i)^{\dots}=e^{\frac{i^n\pi}{2}}$$
As you can see the limit does not exist since $i^4$ oscillates between $1$,$-1$, $i$, and $-i$.

Comment: $i^i = e^{-{\pi \over 2}}$.

Comment: @copper.hat true, i was just writing $-1$ as $i^2$ to show the trend

Comment: Ah, I missed your point.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, thanks, I was actually trying to ask as if it was a power tower where each new exponent is to the power of the last one not the whole thing. But I think there's already a thread answering that

Comment: @Tom, yes you can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180936/complex-towers-iii).

Comment: I think the question is about the power tower. That is, the limit of the sequence defined recursively by $z_1=i$, $z_{n+1}=i^{z_n}$. You are (in my opinion mistakenly) looking at the recursion $z_{n+1}=z_n^i$ instead.