# Infinite exponentiation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, geometry, convergence-divergence, tetration

It started as an exercise for my students.
Calculate $i^i$, then $i^{i^{i}}$ and make a conjecture if we follow that pattern.

If we define $u_n=i$ and $$u_{n+1}=i^{z_n}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}z_n}$$

Then, naming $a_n$ and $b_n$ the real and imaginary part of $z_n$, we have:
$$a_{n+1}+i b_{n+1}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(a_n+i b_n)}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}b_n} \left( \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}a_n\right) +i \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}a_n\right) \right)$$
Thus, we have :
$$a_{n+1}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}b_n} \cdot \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}a_n\right) \qquad b_{n+1}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}b_n} \cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a_n\right)$$

Suppose we manage to prove that those sequences converge then if
$$\ell = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}\ell}$$
Naming $W$ (Lambert function) the log product, we obtain :
$$-\frac{i\pi}{2}\ell \cdot e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}\ell}=-\frac{i \pi}{2} \Rightarrow 
w e^w =-\frac{i \pi}{2} \quad \text{where} \quad w=-\frac{i\pi}{2}\ell
$$

$$\ell =\frac{2i}{\pi} W\left(-i\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \approx 0.43828 + 0.36059 i$$

This seems to be ok since the following Python program gives close results:

```
z = complex(0,1)
from math import exp, cos, sin, pi
l = complex(0.43828271856492007, 0.3605987950798971)

def cexp(z):
    a, b = z.real, z.imag
    return complex(exp(a) * cos(b), exp(a) * sin(b))

def f(z):
    return cexp(complex(0,1) * pi/2 * z)
    
x, y = [[0], [0], [0]], [[1], [1], [1]]
for j in range(100):
    z = f(z)
    x[j % 3].append(z.real)
    y[j % 3].append(z.imag)

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i], "o" + "rgb"[i])
```

[image: Complex plot]

One of my brillant student (Esteban Sabatier) remarks this :

The sequence $w_n - \ell$ where $w_n=z_{3n}$ seems to be decreasing in module to $0$ forming a spiral, (it is also the case for $z_{3n+1}-\ell$, $z_{3n+2}-\ell$) but sadly $w_n-\ell$ is not geometric...

My question is how can I prove those sequences converge.

Comment: See Archibald James Macintyre, [*Convergence of* $i^{i^{i\ldots}}$](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-01/S0002-9939-1966-0188417-4/S0002-9939-1966-0188417-4.pdf), **Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society** 17 #1 (February 1966) p. 67. See also Shell's [1962 paper](https://community.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-05/S0002-9939-1962-0141910-9/S0002-9939-1962-0141910-9.pdf). FYI, what you're asking about is an infinite exponential, NOT an infinite tetration -- infinite sum, infinite product, infinite exponential, infinite tetration, etc. are the "continued operation" notions.

Comment: There should already exist a question here about convergence of $i^{i^i\dots}$.  Indeed, my answer for it had a picture.  But the search here could not find it.

Comment: @GEdgar: I tried [infinite + exponential + "GEdgar" + Stack Exchange](https://www.google.com/search?q=infinite+exponential+%22GEdgar%22+Stack+exchange), then I clicked on "More results from math.stackexchange.com" for the top group of hits, and then saw "Infinite powering by i [duplicate]" as the 6th hit, which had [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/336900/13130) you're probably thinking of. alati ahmad -- You'll also want to look at [Complex towers: $i^{i^{i^{...}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180936/13130) and the questions linked to it (see top right side of web page).

Comment: Thank you @Dave L.Renfro for your answer.

Comment: *Thank you Dave L.Renfro for your answer.* --- FYI, I didn't know about those other MSE questions (at least, I didn't initially remember them; I'm sure I saw them when they originally appeared) when I wrote my 1st comment. I only found them when I was looking for @GEdgar's answer (basis of my 2nd comment), and surprisingly I found and looked through the "Infinite powering by $i$ [duplicate]" question first (which also happened to be where GEdgar's answer was), and only afterwards (by looking at the linked questions) did I find "Complex towers: $i^{i^{i^{...}}}$".